# Dealing with API endpoints in flutter

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, flutter-web

I have started learning to code since a few days back, and am only familiar with HTML/CSS/JS, and basics of **dart/flutter**

I am working on a **Random quotes generator** App project.

**I HAVE THIS API ENDPOINT** - https://winterly-backend.herokuapp.com/quote. Which **returns a json** like this

```
{"_id":"5ef5ad3cffd6b60fae11ad24","text":"I never think of the future. It comes soon enough.","author":"Albert Einstein"}
```

For a coding beginner like me. The whole idea of programing in flutter is amazing, but seems very daunting, or say complicated, while learning it.

**QUESTION -**
Which is the fastest in way flutter that I can use to get the json, and use the values inside my widgets?

**IS THERE A FLUTTER PACKAGE I CAN USE FOR THIS** that can make the process faster and shorter?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, install a Json to dart's converter plugin in intelij or vscode. use it to map json to a dart class, and then use DIO package for api calls.

Comment: That sounds really interesting, can you please guide me how to do that Hosein

Comment: i hope https://blog.logrocket.com/networking-flutter-using-dio/ be useful

Comment: Thank you very much.. This can help a lot ❤️